# What's the approach Facebook and Whatsapp uses to show full screen images?

Tags: android, image, facebook, whatsapp

I've noticed that facebook and whatsapp uses the same approach for showing images on fullscreen for Android. They implement a gallery with zoom and swipe to move to next picture exactly the same.

I wonder if this approach is documented anywhere so I can do the same